# Build model with nested model in rspec integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, integration-testing, nested-attributes

I understand that I can do something like in rspec:

```
let(:project) { Project.new }
```

but in my app a project accepts_nested_attributes_for tasks and when I generate the Project form I build a task along with it using:

```
@project = Project.new
@project.tasks.build
```

I need something like:

```
let(:project) { Project.new.tasks.build }
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I do this as a let in my rspec test?

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure if I understand you right..Anyway if Project and Task are models, Project has_many tasks, Task belongs to project, then (with [FactoryGirl gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)):

**factories.rb**

```
  factory :project do
    name "Foo"
  end
  factory :task do
    name "Bar"
    project
  end
```

in **spec**:

```
let(:task) { FactoryGirl.build(:task) }

before { FactoryGirl.build(:project) }
```

Comment: alex, I have used `let(:project) { FactoryGirl.build(:project_with_task) }` that I setup (a factory with a project that has a task) but wasn't sure if this was building a project+task that had values in each of the fields rather than empty form fields. If there's no easy way I'll just stick with this since it should be pretty much doing the same as I want for testing anyway.